# Reducing a 2nd order ODE to a system of 1st order ODEs: chain rule issue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chain-rule

I'm reading a paper and I need to reproduce the following reduction of a second order ODE to a system of two first order ODEs.

Second order ODE:

$$ (a(f))'' + (b(f))' + c(f) + \sigma f' = 0 $$

where f(x) and ' refers to differentiation with respect to x. $\sigma$ is a constant.

According to the paper, if I set

$$ g(x) := -(a(f))'(x)$$

I should get:

$$ f' = -g/a'(f) $$
$$ g' = -g( \sigma + b'(f) )/a'(f) + c(f) $$

This seems like it should be simple enough, but I'm getting confused somewhere in the chain rule. I started by trying to derive the equation for $f'$ by doing this:

$$g=-\frac{da}{dx} = -\frac{da}{df} \frac{df}{dx}  = -\frac{da}{df} f' $$

But then I get

$$ f' = -g / \left(\frac{da}{df}\right) $$

instead of

$$ f' = -g/a'(f) $$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not the way I would have proceeded, but I understand you are trying to follow what the author of the paper did (citation would be nice, a link even nicer).  I think we have to keep in mind that when we differentiate using the chain rule, we are treating $a,b$ as functions of one argument.  Thus $a',b'$ are the derivatives of those unary functions, *evaluated* at (function value) $f$.

Comment: Are you positive it's not a typo in the paper? I followed your algebra and got exactly what you have.

Comment: @hardmath  Ah, yes, I think that I'm confused about the notation.   I was taking the prime to very literally mean "differentiation with respect to x", not "differentiation with respect to the argument of the function".   Basically, I thought that f'=df/dx because the authors said that the prime was "differentiation with respect to x" when they introduced the original ODE.  However, I see now that I should really be thinking of the prime as "differentiation with respect to the argument of the function" instead of associating it with a specific variable.

Comment: @hardmath  Basically, I almost always use the Leibniz notation for derivatives, and so I hadn't really thought about the chain rule in terms of the Lagrange notation.   And then I wasn't interpreting the Lagrange notation correctly and it led to a weird contradiction.   I think I understand now, thank you!    But please let me know if I'm still thinking about this incorrectly.

Comment: @hardmath  The paper is more of a monograph/book.   It's "Traveling Waves in Nonlinear Diffusion-Convection Reaction" by Gilding and Kersner in Progress in Nonlinear Differential Equations and Their Applications, Vol. 60.  The part I was asking about is on pgs 4-5.   A link is:  https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764370718

Comment: My university library is still open, so I can perhaps have a look.  But first I'll try my hand at doing it my way, and see if it turns out the substitution $g(x) = -(a(f(x))'$ is especially felicitous.

Comment: @hardmath   Everything works out with that subsitution and I can get the system of equations for f' and g' that I gave above.  This is great, I feel like I really learned something here!  Also, I found out that you can find a version of the book online, for free at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254859456_Travelling_waves_in_nonlinear_diffusion-convection-reaction/link/541c0de00cf241a65a0bae00/download    The page numbers and content are slightly different, but the results I'm refering to are on pages 5-8.

Comment: I encourage you to write up your own Answer when you find time!

Answer (score 1):

Here, $a(f(x))$ is just a composite function. The chain rule for composite functions is

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \Big(a \big( f(x) \big) \Big) = \frac{df}{dx}\big(f(x)\big)\cdot \frac{da}{dx}(x)= a'(f)\cdot f'(x). $$

Necessarily,

$$g(x) = - (a(f))' =  -a'(f)\cdot f'(x).$$

Comment: Ahh, thank you, my error! I'll change it now.